# Reading an image for a specific pattern in iphone

Tags: iphone, image, uiimageview, uiimage

I am working on a application where I need to capture an image and detect a specific patterns (e.g lines, circle and dots).

Is it possible to read the image for the patterns?

Thanks
Pankaj

Comment: Your question is way too vague, but you will probably want to look at a library such as OpenCV: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

Answer (score 2):

it's been asked *a lot* on the web.

I believe this is the best start:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/03_MediaCapture.html

(Read a little, then browse to **Processing Frames of Video**)

Cheers,

Oded.

Comment: Sorry you may want a still image, and not raw video footage. But it's a good start still